# How to fix "Date Format" issue in Talend

Tags: java, talend

Input is:

A CSV file - with Date input 2/15/2019.

And Output should be:

> 3 columns output  Fri, Feb 15 00:00:00 IST 2019;  15 February 2019
>   India Standard Time;  Fri, Feb 15 00:00:00 EST 2019

Followed below steps:
In tjava component, I have added the code -

```
Date D=TalendDate.parseDate("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", "02/15/2019 00:00:00");
System.out.println(D.toString());
```

So I got the below output:

> [statistics] connecting to socket on port 3847 [statistics] connected
>   Fri Feb 15 00:00:00 IST 2019 [statistics] disconnected

But I am looking the output in below format:

> 3 columns output  Fri, Feb 15 00:00:00 IST 2019; 15 February 2019
>   India Standard Time;  Fri, Feb 15 00:00:00 EST 2019

Appreciate you help. 
Thank you!

Comment: so, it not clear - do you want from 1 input column to have 3 different output columns?

Comment: yes, as I explained above- I have one input date and looking for the output in three columns with different date format. Fri, Feb 15 00:00:00 IST 2019; 15 February 2019 India Standard Time; Fri, Feb 15 00:00:00 EST 2019

Comment: still not all - IST and India Standard Time it is the same just different format, but EST it different. why in your case time is the same if it 10:30 difference? do you need just  replace IST to EST or you need to print different time with proper calculation? if it just replace with the same time (always 00:00:00) it simple

Answer (score 0):

For the first 2 columns it easy:

First of all, you do not need to parse the string, you could define the column as a date with date pattern `"MM/dd/yyyy"`,

then in tMap (tJavaFlex) define output columns with values:

- `TalendDate.formatDate("EEE, d MMMM HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",row1.date)`
- `TalendDate.formatDate("dd MMMM yyyy zzzz",row1.date)`

For 3rd could be updated after clarification

> good resource for testing - [Java Date Format Tester](http://www.sdfonlinetester.info/#)

Comment: Thank you so much! Got the result.

Comment: Hi, instead of 'tmap', which other component use to get the same output?

Comment: it just a functions you could use it anywhere - System.out.println(bla-bla) or assign to any String variable. tmap is most easiest way split 1 column to 3, but you could do this in tJavaRow as well

Comment: Thanks for your reply!     With 'tjavaFlex', I got below output in console..that is correct but actually I want the same output in 3 different rows. Can you please suggest the missing steps here  :                                                              
 Tue, 15 January 00:02:00 IST 2019
15 January 2019 India Standard Time
Tue, 15 January 00:02:00 EST 2019
Tue, 23 January 00:03:00 IST 2018
23 January 2018 India Standard Time
Tue, 23 January 00:03:00 EST 2018
Sat, 28 January 00:02:00 IST 2017
28 January 2017 India Standard Time
Sat, 28 January 00:02:00 EST 2017

Comment: Expected result got with 'tjavarow' component. Thanks!

Comment: Here in the last column, currently the dateformat is in EST but not showing the time difference, it's showing the actual IST time..my requirement is dateformat should be in IST but the values should be in EST. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Issue resolved with below codes:                                                                    
String inptdate = input_row.Date;
SimpleDateFormat sdfgmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
sdfgmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
SimpleDateFormat sdfmad = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy 'at' hh:mma z");
sdfmad.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
Date date = sdfgmt.parse(inptdate); 
      //System.out.println("EST:\t" + sdfmad.format(date));